# How to modify JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I try to change JPanel.
My main class

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        }
    }
```

MyFrame class. Here I add JPanel and implement ActionListener

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    MyPanel myPanel;
    JButton myButton = new JButton("reset");
    public MyFrame(){
        this.setSize(300, 500);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        myButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(myButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        myPanel = new MyPanel();
        myPanel.setButtons(3);

        this.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource().equals(myButton)){
            System.out.println("click");
            this.remove(myPanel);
            myPanel.setButtons(5);
            this.add(myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            //I want to change number of buttons on MyPanel to 5
        }
    }
}
```

And MyPanel class

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    JButton[] buttons;
    public MyPanel(){
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    }

    public void setButtons(int x){
        buttons = new JButton[x];
        this.removeAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            buttons[i] = new JButton(i+"");
            this.add(buttons[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

What I expected is after I click on "reset" button I want change JPanel (remowe three existing buttons and add five).
And it changes, but only after I resize window. Why?

Comment: Swing is lazy when it comes to updating the UI, it leaves it up to you to decide when it should be done (as the operation can be expensive) - so, you need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you are changing, which, in your case, should be done at the end of the `ActionListener`

Comment: thanks, it works! :)

Comment: As rightly suggested by @MadProgrammer, the thing that needs to be implemented, along with that do have a look at  [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), this makes the work easy, as it is meant for this very requirement, as mentioned in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the frame that it should re-do the layout after you changed the components. So add one line to our action listener method:

```
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {
        if ( event.getSource().equals( myButton ) ) {
            System.out.println( "click" );
            this.remove( myPanel );
            myPanel.setButtons( 5 );
            this.add( myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
            revalidate(); // <-- tell frame to update!
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @dosenfant's code, you could also repaint before revalidating.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event ) {
    if ( event.getSource().equals( myButton ) ) {
        System.out.println( "click" );
        this.remove( myPanel );
        myPanel.setButtons( 5 );
        this.add( myPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        repaint();
        revalidate(); 
    }
}
```